# What is the reasoning to keep the claim edge after the resource is used?

Tags: algorithm, operating-system

> Avoidance requires that the system will never enter an unsafe state, so an algorithm must pick a safe sequence of events and processes for execution. One such algorithm is the resource-allocation graph algorithm. A claim edge Pi → Rj indicates that process Pi may request resource Rj which is represented by a dashed line. A claim edge is converted to a request edge when a process requests a resource. When a resource is released by a process, the assignment reconverts to a claim edge. Resources must be claimed a priori in the system.

For what reason do we reconvert to a claim edge?

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason it was there in the first place, to tell the operating system that the process **may** request this resource.

Even if the process released the resource, it still might request it again in the future.